# Debug current open Flutter file in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am writing a Flutter tutorial project in VS Code with multiple `main()` functions.

For example:

```
main.dart  //Contains a main() function
step1.dart //Contains a main() function
step2.dart //Contains a main() function
```

If I have `step1.dart` open, then pressing F5 runs `main.dart` and not `step1.dart` in debug mode.

I can hover the mouse over the `main()` function in `step1.dart`, and then select 'debug' from the context menu. This works as expected and runs `step1.dart` in debug. However, there is no associated shortcut.

What can I press to run the active open file in debug mode, not `main.dart`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as I have experience of having multiple flutter projects on a workspace (not too good feedback at all), the key is to set the pre-build process configuration file `.vscode/launch.json`, you can get more info on [debugging#_launch-configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations).

When you create the file, it will look something like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
        }
    ]
}
```

Then add `"program": "lib/your-entry-point.dart"`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "main",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart"
        },{
            "name": "step1",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/step1.dart"
        },{
            "name": "step2",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/step2.dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will then create the following launch options.

[image: Launch options]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I am hoping to find a solution to just 'run the active file' and not set up a launch configuration, as this needs to be kept up to date with file name changes, etc. Still, very useful to show here. In this instance, the ideal would have been to press something like Shift+F5 and that will run the current open file in debug if it has a main(), without having to manually write a launcher.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! Now the result outcome is descriptive

Answer (score 1):

I made this `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` folder.
Worked like a charm.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Dart: Current File",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here are the variables you can use in `launch.json`.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference